# How can I save a TTreeview to Windows and keep its hierarchical structure?

Tags: delphi

I want to be able to save my Treeview to Windows and keep its hierarchical structure, but cannot seem to get my head around the recursion magic.

Imagine I have two different object types:

```
TMyFolderNode (represents a folder in the tree)
TMyItemNode (represents a node containing a stringlist of text for example)
```

The Treeview will be populated at runtime, and for each node added contains a pointer to either one of those objects - typically the `TMyFolderNode` would represent a parent node for childs of `TMyItemNode`

So basically, if my Treeview looked like this:

[image]

When saving the treeview, the structure in Windows should look like this:

```
..\Vehicles
..\Vehicles\Bikes
..\Vehicles\Cars
..\Vehicles\Cars\Classic
..\Vehicles\Cars\Classic\1996 Shelby Cobra.txt
..\Vehicles\Cars\Classic\Corvette Stingray.txt
..\Vehicles\Cars\Classic\Jaguar E-Type.txt
..\Vehicles\Cars\Tuner
..\Vehicles\Cars\Tuner\Toyota Supra RZ.txt
..\Vehicles\Trucks
```

This is what I tried:

```
procedure SaveTreeViewStructure(TreeView: TTreeView; const OutDirectory: string);
var
  RootDir, SubDir: string;
  Node: TTreeNode;

  // the recursive procedure
  procedure SaveNode(Node: TTreeNode);
  var
    Obj: TObject;
    Child: TTreeNode;
  begin
    Obj := TObject(Node.Data);

    // node type is a folder/parent, so create the folder in windows...
    if Obj.ClassType = TMyFolderNode then
    begin
      ForceDirectories(RootDir + '\' + Node.Text);
    end;

    // node is a type holding data we can save to text file...
    if Obj.Create.ClassType = TMyItemNode then
    begin
      with TMyItemNode(Obj) do
      begin
        // save the file as .txt...
      end;
    end;

    Child := Node.GetFirstChild;
    while Assigned(Child) do
    begin
      SaveNode(Child);
      Child := Child.GetNextSibling;
    end;
  end;

begin
  RootDir   := OutDirectory + '\';
  SubDir    := '';
  Node      := nil;

  if ForceDirectories(RootDir) then // make sure base folder exists first
  begin
    Node := TreeView.Items[0]; // start from the first tree node (TopItem causes problems)
    while Assigned(Node) do // until node is no longer assigned
    begin
      SaveNode(Node); // call the recursive procedure
      Node := Node.GetNextSibling; // go to the next node
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If I try saving just the `TMyFolderNode` nodes they dont get created in the proper child folders etc, and then when I try saving the text `TMyItemNode` I get cannot find file errors (likely because the folders are not saving properly).

Clearly I dont fully understand the logic behind recursion, I know it means to call itself until a condition is met (eg we reached the last node in the tree), but I cannot seem to figure this one out.

So how do I save my Treeview to a base folder in Windows, where the recursive procedure would create the required sub directories and save the regular node items in the correct place?

Is my approach here wrong? I did try first with `for loops` but the folders kept doubling up and other weird things.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using `RootDir` directly in your recursive procedure, pass in the relative path as a parameter and append to that as needed.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks for the tip, I think I have it working but dont have time right now to test. What I did is get the node path to a string, and then pass that as a filepath. I will post later what I changed and hopefully when I test later it is working..

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I posted my answer but maybe you could post your solution too if you wanted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as pointed out by *500 - Internal Server Error* was to change the path I was passing to the recursive procedure.

Also I had to get the path of the node in a string format, and then use that as the new path:

```
function NodeToStringPath(Node: TTreeNode; var Path: string): string;
begin
  Result := '';

  Path := Node.Text + '\' + Path;
  if Node.Level = 0 then
  begin
    Result := Path
  end
  else
    Result := NodeToStringPath(Node.Parent, Path);
end;

function RemoveLastFolder(var S: string): string;
begin
  Result := '';

  repeat
    Delete(S, Length(S), 1)
  until
    (S[Length(S)] = '\') or (S = '');

  Result := S;
end;

procedure SaveTreeViewStructure(TreeView: TTreeView; const OutDirectory: string);
var
  RootDir, SubDir: string;
  Node: TTreeNode;

  // the recursive procedure
  procedure SaveNode(Node: TTreeNode);
  var
    sPath: string;
    Obj: TObject;
    Child: TTreeNode;
  begin
    Obj := TObject(Node.Data);

    // node type is a folder/parent, so create the folder in windows...
    if Obj.ClassType = TMyFolderNode then
    begin
      SubDir := NodeToStringPath(Child, sPath);
      ForceDirectories(RootDir + SubDir);
    end;

    // node is a type holding data we can save to text file...
    if Obj.Create.ClassType = TMyItemNode then
    begin
      with TMyItemNode(Obj) do
      begin
        // save the file as .txt...
        SubDir := NodeToStringPath(Node, sPath);
        SubDir := RemoveLastFolder(SubDir);
        //...
      end;
    end;

    Child := Node.GetFirstChild;
    while Assigned(Child) do
    begin
      SaveNode(Child);
      Child := Child.GetNextSibling;
    end;
  end;

begin
  RootDir   := OutDirectory + '\';
  SubDir    := '';
  Node      := nil;

  if ForceDirectories(RootDir) then // make sure base folder exists first
  begin
    Node := TreeView.Items[0]; // start from the first tree node (TopItem causes problems)
    while Assigned(Node) do // until node is no longer assigned
    begin
      SaveNode(Node); // call the recursive procedure
      Node := Node.GetNextSibling; // go to the next node
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Tested and seems to be working but it is not 100%, also annoyingly though when trying to save the text file node type I needed to remove the last part of the folder name from the string.

Im sure there is a much cleaner way of achieving this but this was the best I could manage, I just need to tweak a few things but it feels like a lot of work just to save the structure of a treeview to windows.